# How to filter array of objects with two-level nesting?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm have a problem with filtering array of objects with two-levels nesting.

I have 2 arrays, first array is one-level nesting and I have code which work well with it.

```
const storyId = 2

const arrayOne = [
      {
        name: 'First',
        storyId: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Second',
        storyId: 2,
      },
      {
        name: 'Third',
        storyId: 3,
      }
    ]

const result = arrayOne.filter(el => el.storyId === storyId)
```

But in my case I need to filter array by value of second level of nesting. So I have a next code:

```
const storyId = 5

let arrayTwo = [
      {
        name: 'First',
        id: 1,
        libraries: {
          nodes: [
            {storyId: 1},
            {storyId: 3},
            {storyId: 5},
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Second',
        id: 2,
        libraries: {
          nodes: [
            {storyId: 4},
            {storyId: 5},
            {storyId: 6},
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Third',
        id: 3,
        libraries: {
          nodes: [
            {storyId: 3},
            {storyId: 2},
            {storyId: 1},
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

And here I'm expect got array of all first-level objects which have inside libraries->nodes storyId: 5

Tell me please how i can filter it. Preferably in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily the most performant way, but this will get only elements with  nodes that have a matching `storyId`

```js
arrayTwo.filter(el => el.libraries.nodes.filter(n => n.storyId === storyId).length > 0)))
```

Comment: The inner `filter` is unnecessary. You don't need to filter the entire `nodes` array and then check if it is empty. You only need to make sure that some of the nodes have the correct story id and stop immediately if one does: `arrayTwo.filter(({libraries: {nodes}}) => nodes.some(n => n.storyId === 5)) `